# Firestore SetOptions.mergeFields doesn't store field

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have this function to store user into Firestore after he successfully registers.

```
//User class
id: String
email: String?
displayName: String?
photoUrl: String?

//updateOrInsertUser method
collectionReference.document(user.id)
            .set(
                user,
                SetOptions.mergeFields(
                    FIELD_photoUrl,
                    FIELD_email,
                    FIELD_displayName
                )
            )
```

But when I call `updateOrInsertUser(user)` only fields that are in `SetOptions` are stored in Firestore, therefore `id` is not stored.

**Is there a simple way to override old values defined in** `SetOptions` **if the document already exists and if there is not doc store everything?**
I don't want to fetch old document before updating :(

*No I don't want to add `id` into `SetOptions`(imagine other use cases when you don't want to override field that already exists in database)*

Answer (score 1):

> But when I call updateOrInsertUser(user) only fields that are in SetOptions are stored in firestore, therefore id is not stored.

This is the normal behaviour since you aren't passing the id to the SetOptions's `mergeFields()` method.

> Is there a simple way to override old values defined in SetOptions if the document already exists and if there is not doc store everything? I don't want to fetch old document before updating :(

The simplest way would be to get the "old" document, change its values and write it back to the database but there is also another approach that can help you change the values within a document and this is by using a `Map` along with a `update()` method call. In code, might look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("photoUrl", FIELD_photoUrl);
user.put("email", FIELD_email);
user.put("displayName", FIELD_displayName);
userDocumentReference.update(user);
```